# Agrupar ids para una misma funcionalidad CSS

Tags: css

Tengo las siguientes líneas de código que hacen algo similar:

```
label[for=nombre]{
    font-weight: bold;
}

label[for=capacidad]{
    font-weight: bold;
}

label[for=descripcion]{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**¿Se pueden agrupar los nombres de los "ids" en este caso del label for, todos en uno mismo desde CSS?** ¿Separado por comas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que es posible, ¿lo has intentado?. Toma atención respecto al valor que asignas al selector de atributos, no refiere al identificador del elemento (ID), refiere al valor del atributo for que por coincidencia podría ser el mismo.

```css
label[for=nombre],
label[for=capacidad],
label[for=descripcion]{
    font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<label for="nombre" id="lbl1">Nombre</label>
<label for="capacidad" id="lbl2">Capacidad</label>
<label for="descripcion" id="lbl3">Descripción</label>
```

Si buscas referirte al identificador del elemento (ID) podrías especificar el selector de etiqueta seguido del identificador, por ejemplo:

```css
label#lbl1,
label#lbl2 {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<label for="nombre" id="lbl1">Nombre</label>
<label for="capacidad" id="lbl2">Capacidad</label>
<label for="descripcion" id="lbl3">Descripción</label>
```

Sin embargo, considera que no es la mejor manera de definir las reglas de estilos, sugiero crear una clase que defina el estilo de la fuente que usará las etiquetas que tu requieras, la idea es indicar al elemento la clase a usar en lugar de indicar al estilo los elementos a afectar, por ejemplo:

```css
.label-style {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<label for="nombre" class="label-style">Nombre</label>
<label for="capacidad">Capacidad</label>
<label for="descripcion" class="label-style">Descripción</label>
```